# Estou com problemas de repetição no python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

```
while True:
  nome = str(input('nome do aluno: '))
if nome == 'sair':
   break
elif nome in notas:
  print(f'\n{nome}',nome.upper())

n1 = float(input('Nota do aluno: '))
n2 = float(input('Segunda nota do aluno: '))
n3 = float(input('terceira nota do aluno: '))
n4 = float(input('Quarta nota do aluno: '))
m = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4

print('media do {}: {:.1}'.format(nome,m))

if m < 5.0:
      print('reprovado')
elif m < 10:
    print('aprovado')
else:
    print('aprovado com Distinção!')
```

Comment: Coloque uma explicação do seu problema, como quer que seu código funcione para pessoa que for lhe ajudar não desfigure o seu programa. Por exemplo eu poderia dizer que removendo a linha `while True:` seu programa vai rodar mas você colocou aí por um motivo, quer que algo se repita indefinidamente, além de que outros problemas vão surgir com esse código.

Comment: Em elif nome in notas: o que vem a ser notas?

Comment: Considerando que os erros de indentação tenham sido apenas erros de escrita.

Answer (score 1):

Repare que em python a sua identação têm impacto no algoritmo, então é fácil notar seu erro... 
note que:

```
while True:
  nome = str(input('nome do aluno: '))
```

é um laco de repetição cujo escopo possui apenas:

```
nome = str(input('nome do aluno: '))
```

logo este laço não possui uma condição para que seja finalizado. Para resolver este problema apenas conserte a identação de seu programa, ficando da senguinte maneira:

```
while True:
    nome = str(input('nome do aluno: '))
    if nome == 'sair':
        break
    elif nome in notas:
        print(f'\n{nome}',nome.upper())

    n1 = float(input('Nota do aluno: '))
    n2 = float(input('Segunda nota do aluno: '))
    n3 = float(input('terceira nota do aluno: '))
    n4 = float(input('Quarta nota do aluno: '))
    m = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4

    print('media do {}: {:.1}'.format(nome,m))

    if m < 5.0:
        print('reprovado')
    elif m < 10:
        print('aprovado')
    else:
        print('aprovado com Distinção!')
```

Entretanto, repare que nesta linha:

```
elif nome in notas:
```

você não definiu 'notas' anteriormente, logo a IDE retorna:

> NameError: name 'notas' is not defined

Para resolver este problema basta retirar essa parte do código, permanecendo assim:

```
elif nome:
```

além disso, da forma que Você formatou a string, o nome será repetido 2 vezes, uma do jeito que o usuário digitou e outra em maiúsculo:

```
print(f'\n{nome}',nome.upper())
```

Saída:

> Jorgim JORGIM

e para resolver basta colocar o `nome.upper()` dentro dos `{}` e seu código final ficará assim:

```
while True:
    nome = str(input('nome do aluno: '))
    if nome == 'sair':
        break
    elif nome:
        print(f'\n{nome.upper()}')

    n1 = float(input('Nota do aluno: '))
    n2 = float(input('Segunda nota do aluno: '))
    n3 = float(input('terceira nota do aluno: '))
    n4 = float(input('Quarta nota do aluno: '))
    m = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4

    print('media do {}: {:.1}'.format(nome,m))

    if m < 5.0:
        print('reprovado')
    elif m < 10:
        print('aprovado')
    else:
        print('aprovado com Distinção!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia David

Cara, olhando o teu código, não haverá loop a nenhum outro item a não ser para a parte:

```
  nome = str(input('nome do aluno: '))
```

Note que em Python a identação é fundamental e, caso você queira que todas operações fiquem dentro do loop, você deverá identar seu  código da seguinte maneira:

```
while True:
    nome = str(input('nome do aluno: '))
    if nome == 'sair':
       break
    elif nome in notas:
      print(f'\n{nome}',nome.upper())

    n1 = float(input('Nota do aluno: '))
    n2 = float(input('Segunda nota do aluno: '))
    n3 = float(input('terceira nota do aluno: '))
    n4 = float(input('Quarta nota do aluno: '))
    m = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4

    print('media do {}: {:.1}'.format(nome,m))

    if m < 5.0:
          print('reprovado')
    elif m < 10:
        print('aprovado')
    else:
        print('aprovado com Distinção!')
```